# Hilbert space and quantum mechanics

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If we consider a vector space $V$ over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, and a linear application $f$
$f:V\rightarrow C$
The set of all functionals $f$ form a vector space $V^{\ast}$, the dual of $V$. And $f(v)$ is noted as $\langle f│v\rangle$, where
$\langle f|\in V^{\ast}$. So  $f(v)=\langle f│v\rangle$, and it is important to note that $\langle f│v\rangle$ is not a scalar product; it is $f$ operating on $v$.
In quantum mechanics books, where $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, and $|\phi\rangle \in L^2$   where $L^2$ is Hilbert space of square summable functions, we see with no explanation that $\langle \phi|r\rangle=\phi(r)^{\ast}$ where $|r\rangle\in\mathbb{R}^3$.
Now $\langle \phi|r\rangle$ is not a scalar product, since $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $L^2$ are two different vector spaces. A scalar product is between two elements of the same vector space.
But then, if $\phi$ is operating on $r$ to yield $\phi(r)^{\ast}$, $L^2$ should be the dual of $\mathbb{R}^3$; which is not.
I would be really grateful for any clarification.

Comment: What is the source of this claim?

Answer (score 1):

The notation you allude to is a very useful, but not rigorous notation used by physicists.

With $|r\rangle$ it is meant the delta function at $r$ so

$$
|r\rangle = \delta(r-x)
$$

Now the above is not a function but a distribution. A distribution applied to a test function $\psi$ is written

$$
\langle r , \psi\rangle
$$

Now the above can be formally written as

$$
\int r(x) \psi(x) dx.
$$

In this way the above looks like the $L^2$ scalar product.

In any case, using the property of the delta function, one has

$$
\langle r , \psi\rangle = \int \delta(r-x) \psi(x) dx = \psi(r).
$$

Comment: Note that $| r \rangle \not\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. It is only formally a state.